# MySQL vs File-Based CMS

Tags: mysql, performance, content-management-system, blogs

I'm looking for a new CMS to host my new blog and I was deciding what the best route would be, either using MySQL or a file-based CMS.

I'll probably be writing on the blog every other day so I'm looking for speed.

Does anybody know which one would be better for speed / security?

Thanks!

Comment: There's too many factors involved. Both file-based and db based may be the best depending on your cod, your system setup and so on. Databases are usually easier to work with, though.

Comment: Are there really any serious file-based CMS?

Comment: @lanzz Yep. [Kirby](http://getkirby.com/) - The problem with Kirby is that you have to do quite a few things before it's setup as a blog.

Comment: But there's lots of file-based blog software.

Comment: @EmilVikström Are they any good when it comes to security though? And easy to setup?

Comment: I have no idea. Why wouldn't they?

Comment: @lanzz - Yes. Barebones CMS is a serious file-based CMS. But it likely isn't appropriate for this scenario since the OP wants a blog more than a CMS. MySQL has the advantage of being searchable - being able to find content you wrote some time ago but can't remember when it was written.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For security, I see storing content in a database as being more secure, as database access requires one more level of authentication than simply storing content in a file.

If a user pokes around your system and finds your include folder, then all content could potentially be exposed by guessing the paths.  Since the database is usually abstracted away from your  front-end application, accessing its content by simply guessing url paths is much harder to do.

In addition, your application will probably only expose certain fields from your database to the front-end, (assuming your database access functions are properly written to prevent things like SQL injection etc).

Unless you expect seriously high volumes of traffic on your site, you probably won't notice much of a difference between reading from a file vs. reading from a database.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend one of the popular ones such as [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/), Wordpress, or Drupal (why re-invent the wheel?).  They're heavily supported by the community, so the standard concerns like security and such are usually found and fixed before you're even aware they existed.  My personal favorite is Joomla because of the extensive collection of [extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that are available, with a great many of them focused on social media such as twitter and facebook to "spread the word" from what you're putting on your site.

Comment: I'm putting of things like WordPress for my blog because as it's just simply a blog with just one page and some posts, WordPress' pile of PHP files and function along with the backend is just too complicated for my blog. I've designed my own backend where you have 2 inputs, title and post. Simple and easy. I see no need to have a complete CMS like WP for that.

Comment: Fair enough, you'd said "I'm looking for a new CMS to...", so threw in my two bits.  It's always the one i recommend to friends because they have it up and running within a few minutes, and it's like Christmas for them when they start using the extensiosn....Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks! Don't get me wrong, I do use WordPress and other CMS' although I didn't feel the whole CMS was required for a simple enough blog.